# Converting HLS with discontinuity tag into MP4 using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm trying to concat all chunks in HLS, into a single mp4 file, using ffmpeg.
I tried the command:
ffmpeg -i   -vcodec copy -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc

However, I noticed that if m3u8 contains discontinuity tag, then the concatenation is not work well, i.e. the video stops during all the missing chunks.

Any idea, how to convert so the video play continuously, namely, ignoring the missing chunks?

Comment: Its discontinuity not disconnectivity

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5419

> FFMPEG Trac ticket #5419
>   HLS EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag is not supported

Answer (score 1):

this problem can be solved by concat protocol

1. first  turn input m3u8 file to a ts list file

   grep -e '^http.*.ts$' input.m3u8 | awk '{print "file", $1}' > all.ts
2. second use all.ts as input to concat into a mp4 file

   ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist 'http,file,tcp' -nostdin -f concat -safe 0 -i all.ts -c copy -movflags faststart -y output.mp4